# Falling RPM's and Stalls after Releasing the Clutch

Tags: mazda, idle, stall, lantis-323

Once my [97 Mazda 323](http://www.auto-data.net/en/?f=showCar&car_id=11162) get's up to normal operating temperature, around say 90 C, the RPM's will occasionally nosedive after taking it out of gear, releasing the clutch and letting off the gas.  What I mean is that they'll dive down to around 200, nearly stalling, and either bounce for a bit between 200 to 750, or rev back up to around 1500 and settle back to normal 750 idle.  A little more rarely it will result in an actual stall.  Rarely in this case meaning maybe once a day, in about 50 kilometers of city driving.

**EDIT**

Something I noticed is that if I *don't* release the clutch, the RPM's will stay stable.  I've also noticed that as the ambient air temp increases the frequency of the problem increases as well.

So I took off the throttle body and this is what it looked like:

[image]

The IAC passage didn't look particularly dirty, but I sprayed some carb cleaner into it from both the manifold side and the intake pipe without taking it off the throttle body.  I also cleaned the throttle plate and sprayed some cleaner into the very nasty, dirty manifold for good measure.  I also reset the ECU after doing this and it seems that the problem has been solved.

Comment: It sounds more like you are having an issue with the idle air control (IAC) valve. You should try to clean it and the upper intake tract.

Comment: Throttle body was replaced by previous owner about a year ago and is very clean - I would assume that they cleaned the IAC at the same time, or would that be too much of an assumption to make?

Comment: @Paulster2 Convert to an answer and I'll accept it - cleaned the IAC and throttle body, plus reset the ECU today and after driving about 20 km city it looks like the problem has went away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a problem with the Idle Air Control (IAC) valve, or something in that general vicinity. You should try to clean it and the upper intake tract.